# Issues with using # for deep linking into dynamic apps?

Tags: apache-flex, flash, browser, deep-linking

I have a Flex app I built. It uses the `BrowserManager` class to listen for changes in the `#` part of the URL. When a change is made to the hash my application updates accordingly so you can link directly to a state of the application. Also inside my programming when a user clicks something, all I do is use the `BrowserManager` to update the `#` and then my listener will apply the correct changes once its finished. I believe this is the best practice way to doing this in Flex.

I have some issues though. When using the Back button in FF or IE, it gets "stuck". for example if the hash is like `#state4` clicking the back button will take you to `#state3` then `#state2` but sometimes get stuck where you can be on `#state3` click the back button, see it flicker to `#state2` real quick then change back to `#state3` preventing you from going back any further in your history.

Now in Chrome its even worse. As you make your way through the application the hash `#` is updated and so the application updates (proving that the app can see changes in the hash since thats the only way it updates). but when you click the back button, the hash `#` goes back to its previous state, but my application does not as if it is unaware the hash is changing.

I find this very bizarre and don't know what to make of it. I was wondering if anyone else had experienced this or knows what might be the issue.

To see it in action go [here](http://www.kranichs.com/design-my-own-everlon/) and navigate the builder (it will ask you to click jewelry type, metal, etc.) a few times until you see the big red *add to cart* button, then try to use your back button to get back to this page.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the History Manager.  Have a look on the http://www.nbilyk.com/blog/1/68/flex-history-manager